# How can I cross a pyspark subsets of a dataframe with two columns of another dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, subset, permutation

## Problem

How can I mark in a subset of a pyspark dataframe based on another dataframe?

In Table A the subset is defined by a code in the column `code`. For each code, we have multiple registers. We have one column, `servico`. In Table B we have the same columns `cod_1` and `cod_2` and the column we want to cross with Table A. In case the `cod_1` and `cod_2`are present in the subset defined by `code` in the Table A column `servico`, we fill the Table A column `rule` in the register with the `cod_2` with the values in Table B `rule`.

## Requirements

The only restriction is that everything needs to be done in pyspark or SQL without collect(). I want to maximize performance in a Databricks server.

## Example

Table A is defined by:

```
table_a= spark.createDataFrame([
        ('123', 'A1',''), 
        ('123', 'E1',''),
        ('123', 'A3',''),
        ('123', 'B1',''),
        ('123', 'B2',''),
        ('123', 'B3',''),
        ('321', 'C1',''),
        ('321', 'C2',''),
        ('321', 'C3',''),
        ('321', 'C4',''),
        ('321', 'D1',''),
    ],
    ['code', 'servico', 'rule'] 
)
```

Table B is defined by:

```
table_b = spark.createDataFrame([
        ('E1', 'A1','aaa'), 
        ('E2', 'A2','bbb'),
        ('F1', 'A3','ccc'),
        ('F2', 'B1','ddd'),
        ('F3', 'B2','eee'),
        ('G1', 'B3','fff'),
        ('G2', 'C1','ggg'),
        ('G3', 'C2','hhh'),
        ('G4', 'C3','iii'),
        ('H1', 'C4','jjj'),
        ('H2', 'D1','kkk'),
    ],
    ['cod_1', 'cod_2', 'rule'] 
)
```

The expected result is:

```
result = spark.createDataFrame([
        ('123', 'A1','aaa'), 
        ('123', 'E1',''),
        ('123', 'A3',''),
        ('123', 'B1',''),
        ('123', 'B2',''),
        ('123', 'B3',''),
        ('321', 'C1',''),
        ('321', 'C2',''),
        ('321', 'C3',''),
        ('321', 'C4',''),
        ('321', 'D1',''),
    ],
    ['code', 'servico', 'rule'] 
)
```

The only register that is filled with the Table B is the first because we find both `A1` and `E1` for the code `123`.

Comment: I have two question: 1. Where is the `cod` column in your table_a example? 2. In your expected result, why the second row, `('123', 'E1','')`, doesn't need to be filled with 'aaa'? `E1` and `A1` is a combination right?

Comment: 1. the `cod` is the `servico`. I will fix in the example. Thanks. 

2. You can also mark both E1 and A1. I think that mark only E1 it is easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prevent bulky dataframe (i.e table a join table a to get all the combination) and handle the key ordering, I collect all the servico of each code first:

```
table_a_agg = table_a\
    .withColumn('set_of_servico', func.collect_set('servico').over(Window.partitionBy('code')).cast(types.StringType()))
table_a_agg.show(100, False)
+----+-------+----+------------------------+
|code|servico|rule|set_of_servico          |
+----+-------+----+------------------------+
|123 |A1     |    |[B1, A3, A1, B2, E1, B3]|
|123 |E1     |    |[B1, A3, A1, B2, E1, B3]|
|123 |A3     |    |[B1, A3, A1, B2, E1, B3]|
|123 |B1     |    |[B1, A3, A1, B2, E1, B3]|
|123 |B2     |    |[B1, A3, A1, B2, E1, B3]|
|123 |B3     |    |[B1, A3, A1, B2, E1, B3]|
|321 |C1     |    |[C4, C3, D1, C1, C2]    |
|321 |C2     |    |[C4, C3, D1, C1, C2]    |
|321 |C3     |    |[C4, C3, D1, C1, C2]    |
|321 |C4     |    |[C4, C3, D1, C1, C2]    |
|321 |D1     |    |[C4, C3, D1, C1, C2]    |
+----+-------+----+------------------------+
```

The reason, why the `set_of_servico` is casted to string type, is for the joining. To do the joining, we can check if `cod_1` and `cod_2` in `set_of_servico`

```
result = table_a_agg.select('code', 'servico', 'set_of_servico').alias('a')\
    .join(table_b.alias('b'), 
          [func.col('a.set_of_servico').contains(func.col('b.cod_1')), func.col('a.set_of_servico').contains(func.col('b.cod_2'))], 
          how='left')
+----+-------+------------------------+-----+-----+----+
|code|servico|set_of_servico          |cod_1|cod_2|rule|
+----+-------+------------------------+-----+-----+----+
|123 |A1     |[B1, A3, A1, B2, E1, B3]|E1   |A1   |aaa |
|123 |E1     |[B1, A3, A1, B2, E1, B3]|E1   |A1   |aaa |
|123 |A3     |[B1, A3, A1, B2, E1, B3]|E1   |A1   |aaa |
|123 |B1     |[B1, A3, A1, B2, E1, B3]|E1   |A1   |aaa |
|123 |B2     |[B1, A3, A1, B2, E1, B3]|E1   |A1   |aaa |
|123 |B3     |[B1, A3, A1, B2, E1, B3]|E1   |A1   |aaa |
|321 |C1     |[C4, C3, D1, C1, C2]    |null |null |null|
|321 |C2     |[C4, C3, D1, C1, C2]    |null |null |null|
|321 |C3     |[C4, C3, D1, C1, C2]    |null |null |null|
|321 |C4     |[C4, C3, D1, C1, C2]    |null |null |null|
|321 |D1     |[C4, C3, D1, C1, C2]    |null |null |null|
+----+-------+------------------------+-----+-----+----+
```

Then we can check if servico equal to cod_1 and cod_2 to filter out the row that have joining result, but actually it's not in the combination:

```
result = result\
    .select(
        'code',
        'servico',
        func.when((func.col('servico')==func.col('cod_1'))|(func.col('servico')==func.col('cod_2')), func.col('rule')).otherwise(func.lit(None)).alias('rule')
    )
result.show(100, False)
+----+-------+----+
|code|servico|rule|
+----+-------+----+
|123 |A1     |aaa |
|123 |E1     |aaa |
|123 |A3     |null|
|123 |B1     |null|
|123 |B2     |null|
|123 |B3     |null|
|321 |C1     |null|
|321 |C2     |null|
|321 |C3     |null|
|321 |C4     |null|
|321 |D1     |null|
+----+-------+----+
```